# php's file_get_contents fails but ping works

Tags: php, twitter, file-get-contents, ping

i am trying to write a very simple php script to test if host `api.twitter.com` is up. but when i do

```
file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com')
```

then i get the error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com):
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
```

a simple `ping` on the command line works fine, and `file_get_contents` works fine on other urls, eg `http://google.com`.

before i give `curl` a try i thought i would see if i am doing something wrong with `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: Copy the URL https://api.twitter.com in your browser : it really IS a 404.

Comment: how come it pings ok then?

Comment: Ping is ICMP, HTTP is TCP.

Comment: api.twitter.com is not a valid link.. thats why you getting 404.. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api is valid.. I am not sure what you trying to do reading this page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://api.twitter.com on its own does actually return a 404 - its normal. If you're wanting to interact with the API you have to use something like:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json
```

Documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline

Comment: thanks. i think i will take the 404 as the server being up and differentiate between this and the server being unreachable (when api.twitter.com is down)